# SQL Query , joins and where

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run a rather simple query, but it seems to return absolutely no result;

```
$q  = "SELECT DISTINCT c.product_sku, c.compare_at, c.product_discount_id, d.amount FROM #__{vm}_product as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN #__vm_product_discount as d ON d.discount_id = c.product_discount_id WHERE";
$q .= "c.vendor_id='".$_SESSION['ps_vendor_id']."' ";
$q .= "AND #__{vm}_product.product_publish='Y' ";
$q .= "AND #__{vm}_product.isfront='1' ";
$q .= "AND c.isfront='1' ";
```

There are other queries after the above, but even when I comment out everything and use only one WHERE clause, nothing is returned. When I remove it, it works. All the below code did work  until I added the JOIN.

I'm new to using joins, I'm guessing something about them makes the WHERE not work, but maybe I just messed up the code along the way, so perhaps better trained eyes could find an issue here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is just ugly formatted. run it at print out what is inside the q variable. preferable include \n to return rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, you do not have any space between the WHERE and the c.vendor_id.  So your SQL would look like:   blah blah WHEREc.vendor_id= blah blah.  So the first thing to try would be to add a space after the WHERE in the first line.

If there's more to this problem than a missing space, please could you post an example of the actual SQL in $q that is being run, rather than the code used to produce it?  Your code does not contain a liberal sprinkling of protective measures such as addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string(), so it's possible that there's something nasty in there.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed this stupid oversight, thanks a lot for pointing it out!